# How to find multiple and dynamic values using JPA and Specifications with spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, dictionary, jpa, spring-data-jpa, dynamic-queries

I am using Sring boot and I have an entity **Product** that has a Map<String,String> that represent the attributes of the product. I want do a controller that permit the user to send a List of attributes with the comparision operator of each attribute, and then find the Products that meet the conditions.

I tried doing the following:

This is my **Entity**

```
@Entity
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    @ElementCollection
    @MapKeyColumn(name="name")
    @Column(name="value")
    private Map<String,String> attributes;
}
```

Then I use a **searchCriteria** to define of what attribute I am searching

```
public class SearchCriteria {
    private String key;
    private String operation;
    private String value;
}
```

Finally my Specification that for now only find by a single attribute, but this is the part that does not work because of the following error: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Basic paths cannot be dereferenced`

```
public class ProductSpecification implements Specification<Product>{

    private SearchCriteria searchCriteria;

    public ProductSpecification(SearchCriteria searchCriteria) {
        this.searchCriteria = searchCriteria;
    }

    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Product> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
        String operation = searchCriteria.getOperation();
        switch (operation) {
            case "==":
                return criteriaBuilder.equal(root.join("attributes").get(searchCriteria.getKey()),searchCriteria.getValue());      
            case "<":
                return criteriaBuilder.lessThan(root.join("attributes").get(searchCriteria.getKey()),searchCriteria.getValue());
            case ">":
                return criteriaBuilder.greaterThan(root.join("attributes").get(searchCriteria.getKey()),searchCriteria.getValue());
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

```
@Service
public class ProductService {

    @Autowired
    ProductRepository productRepository;

    public List<Product> findBy(SearchCriteria searchCriteria){
        ProductSpecification productSpecification = new ProductSpecification(searchCriteria);
        return productRepository.findAll(productSpecification);
    }
```

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/api/product")
public class ProductController {

    @Autowired
    ProductService productService;

    @GetMapping("findBy")
    public ResponseEntity<?> findBy(@RequestBody SearchCriteria searchCriteria){
        List<Product> products = productService.findBy(searchCriteria);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(products, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Comment: If I recall correctly you can't use a `join` on `attributes` because it is a basic (non-entity) field, which is not allowed in JPA criteria queries. You might need to create an Expression from the root attributes, use the value, create a predicate and then add the predicate to the criteria. I'm not in my pc right now to add an answer. Hope someone else can help you out.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Jorge. I finally used a MapJoin<Product, String, String>. This join allows access to both the key and the value. So, I created two predicates, one for the key and another for the value, and then I created an 'and' predicate with both.

Comment: Awesome! Glad to be of help!

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved it in the following way.

```
    @Override
public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Product> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
    String operation = searchCriteria.getOperation();
    MapJoin<Product,String, String> attributesJoin = root.joinMap("attributes"); 

    switch (operation) {
        case "==":
            Predicate predicateKey = criteriaBuilder.equal(attributesJoin.key(), searchCriteria.getKey());
            Predicate predicateValue = criteriaBuilder.equal(attributesJoin.value(), searchCriteria.getValue());
            return criteriaBuilder.and(predicateKey,predicateValue);
```